# Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using nostra's universal image loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

I am facing a problem with displayImage(). The following scenario occurs :

"I call the imageView.displayImage() and the image is not loaded ( its running in thread)
Then I call the imageView.displayImage() second time now since the second image is smaller the second image is shown in imageView but after a few seconds the first image replaces the second image."

How can I avoid the second image being replaced by the previous image? Is there any option to be set for that?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Why are you loading two different images in the same `ImageView`?

Comment: I am initially loading an image into the imageView (since its large its still loading ) now i swipe so another image is loaded after a few seconds the previous image loading is finished and it replaces the second one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the onLoadingComplete() callback of the imageLoader.loadImage() we get the imageUri as parameter check it with the current imageUrl if same only then set the image in the imageView. Note the current imageUrl should be a member variable and not a final variable

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code can be help for you

```
private void LoadBackground(){
    ParseFile f = messageObject.getParseFile("image");
    voiceFile = messageObject.getParseFile("");
    if( f == null) return;
    String fpath = f.getUrl().toString();
    if(f.getUrl() == null) return;
    if (!fpath.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        if (!fpath.startsWith("http://") && !fpath.startsWith("https://")) {
            Log.d("refreshProfile",fpath);
            File imgFile = new File(fpath);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if (bitmap != null) {
                imgBg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        } else {
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(fpath, imgBg,
                DisplayImageOption.getDisplayImage(),
                new AnimateFirstDisplayListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Following is code for listener

```
public class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

  public static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

     @Override
     public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
       if (loadedImage != null) {
           ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
           boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
           if (firstDisplay) {
               FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
               displayedImages.add(imageUri);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

DisplayImageOption.java

```
public class DisplayImageOption {

   public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayImage() {

       DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
       .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.background)
       .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.background)
       .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.background)
       .cacheInMemory(true)
       .cacheOnDisk(true)
       .considerExifParams(true)
       .build();
       return options;

   }

   public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayRoundedImage() {

       DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
       .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
       .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
       .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
       .cacheInMemory(true)
       .cacheOnDisk(true)
       .considerExifParams(true)
       .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(100))
       .build();

       return options;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### maybe you can do like following code:

```
new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_avatar_female)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_avatar_female)
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.default_avatar_female).build();
```

by showImageOnLoading.

Comment: I'm not very sure what's his purpose !